# Tensorflow RNN LSTM output explanation

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I have two questions related the [tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTMCell). Let's look at the following code:

```
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
rnn1 = tf.keras.layers.RNN(tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(4))
output = rnn1(inputs)

rnn2 = tf.keras.layers.RNN(
   tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(4),
   return_sequences=True,
   return_state=True)
whole_seq_output, final_memory_state, final_carry_state = rnn2(inputs)
```

From the outputs of `rnn2`, I can see that the `final_memory_state` is contained in the `whole_seq_output`:

```
tf.reduce_all(whole_seq_output[:,-1,:]==final_memory_state)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True>
```

Hence, I think the `final_memory_state` is the final cell state, while the `whole_seq_output` contains all the cell states. Also, the `final_carry_state` is the final hidden state. The cell state and hidden state are referred to as C_t and h_t in this well-known [tutorial](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/). Is my understanding correct?

Also, from `rnn1`, the `output` is not one of `final_memory_state` or `final_carry_state`:

```
>>> tf.reduce_all(output == final_carry_state)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=False>
>>> tf.reduce_all(output == final_memory_state)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=False>
```

I think the only difference between the `rnn1` and `rnn2` is how the values are returned, so the `output` should be one of `final_memory_state` or `final_carry_state`. Could you help explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing several times, it turns out that the `whole_seq_output` contains all the outputs at different time steps while the `final_memory_state` is the output at the final time step. They refer to the `h_t` in the aforementioned tutorial.
Also, `final_carry_state` is the cell state (i.e., the `C_t` in the tutorial).
Lastly, `output` is indeed `final_memory_state`. Their values should be the same if the same cell is used (I used two different cells).

```
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
cell = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(4)
rnn1 = tf.keras.layers.RNN(cell)
output = rnn1(inputs)

rnn2 = tf.keras.layers.RNN(
   cell,
   return_sequences=True,
   return_state=True)
whole_seq_output, final_memory_state, final_carry_state = rnn2(inputs)
```